# Is there a name for endomorphisms satisfying a condition weaker than nilpotence?

Tags: notation, definition, nilpotence

**The context.**

An endomorphism $u\in \mathcal L(E)$ is called *nilpotent* if, and only if,

$$\exists n\geqslant 0,\quad \forall x\in E,\quad u^n(x)=0.\qquad (\star)$$

For example,

$$\begin{matrix}D\colon& \mathbb R_{\leqslant n}[X] & \to &\mathbb R_{\leqslant n}[X] \\ & P&\mapsto &P'\end{matrix}$$

(where $\mathbb R_{\leqslant n}[X]$ stands for polynomials of $\mathbb R[x]$ of degree $\leqslant n$) is nilpotent since

$$\forall P\in \mathbb R_{\leqslant n}[X],\quad D^{n+1}(P)=0.$$

**The question.**

If we consider this time

$$\begin{matrix}D\colon & \mathbb R[X] & \to &\mathbb R[X] \\ & P&\mapsto &P'\end{matrix}$$

it is not nilpotent anymore since it only verifies

$$\forall P\in \mathbb R[X],\quad \exists n\geqslant 0,\quad D^n(P)=0.$$

> Does this type of endomorphism (where the quantifiers have been exchanged in the definition $(\star)$) have a name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a locally nilpotent operator, here is a [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22807/is-there-an-accepted-term-for-locally-nilpotent-linear-operators) from another math.stackexchange question (I couldn't find official source on this).

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that, unlike "nilpotent", the terminology "locally nilpotent" is not so standard that all mathematicians would be expected to understand it.  For example, if I wrote the phrase "locally nilpotent" in a paper, I'd include its definition; I wouldn't feel obligated to do the same for "nilpotent".

Comment: I agree. On the other hand it is the first natural thing one could think (it was the first name immediately coming in mind when I read this question, and indeed already some people called such operators this way).